# Finite union of algebraic affine varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm studying Commutative algebra and Algebraic Geometry. I have proved the following proposition:

$V(I)∪V(J)=V(IJ)=V(I∩J)$

I would know why sometimes is better to use the product of ideals instead of the intersection.

Another question I was thinking of is... if infinite union of algebraic affine varieties isn't an algebraic affine variety but the intersection of ideals is an ideal, what is wrong with that?

Thank you so much.

Comment: That formula that you proved above only works for finitely many ideals. Look at the proof again, you specifically use the fact that you have only two (or finitely many of them). The proof does not generalize.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I was expecting someone who knows an example in which is better to use the formula with the product of the ideals instead of the intersection. I mean, is there any difference between them? Is something related to multiplicity or something like that?

Comment: You want the operation corresponding to taking a union. You probably want $X \cup X = X$, and that only happens if you use the intersection of the ideals. In the world of varieties, the intersection of two radical ideals is radical, so the intersection is really the thing you want.